# Resize array in php

Tags: php

I need to change size of 2D array.

I use POST method to set new size and actual size is stored in SESSION variable.

This is how I initialize my array:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['array'])) {
$_SESSION['array']=array(array());
$_SESSION['array']=array_fill(0, $_SESSION['sz'], array_fill(0, $_SESSION['sx'], 0));}
```

When I add more rows It works:

```
if (isset($_POST['sz'])) {
if($_POST['sz']>$_SESSION['sz']){
    array_pad( $_SESSION['array'], $_POST['sz'], array_fill(0, $_SESSION['sx'], 0 ));
}
$_SESSION['sz'] = $_POST['sz'];}
```

but when I try to add more colums, there is an error:

```
if (isset($_POST['sx'])) {
if($_POST['sx']>$_SESSION['sx']){
    for ($row = 0; $row < $_SESSION['sz']; $row++) {
        array_pad($_SESSION['array'][$row], $_POST['sx'], 0);
    }
}
$_SESSION['sx'] = $_POST['sx'];}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I use for loop to print array, and when I change x size it prints nothing but when I changed z size It printed correctly

Comment: That's because array_pad returns a copy of the array, the changes aren't done in place

Comment: I assigned returned value to the old array and now it works. Thank you!